# Value equal to ANY value in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

just wondering if there is any way of checking if Value A is equal to ANY value within an array (without using large loop functions) - sort of like a "Where" function.

e.g.

```
if (DataRow[column1value] == <any value within>Array A[])
{
//do...
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know C# - but this looks like it might be what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 or higher, using LINQ:

```
bool found = yourArray.Contains(yourValue);
```

In earlier versions of the framework:

```
bool found = Array.IndexOf(yourArray, yourValue) > -1;
```

Comment: I like your answer better than the accepted one, because it answers situations in various versions.

Comment: +1 Agree with Robert. This question is askeda great deal on stackoverflow, eh?

Comment: Going to change... answer is same as previously chosen answer, but also provides other versions of framework. Nice one.

Answer (score 8):

```
if(myArray.Contains(A)){...}
```

Comment: This would use `Enumerable.Contains` extension method. Normally it's a perfectly appropriate solution, but it does incur a relatively small perf penalty because it works via `IEnumerable`. One can also use `Array.IndexOf(array, value) >= 0`, which only works on arrays, and is somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourArray.Any(item => item != null && item.Equals(yourvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Array.Contains

EDIT.

Im sorry, thisis what i meant

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
if (array.Contains(5))
{
}
```

Comment: but there is ((ICollection)array).Contains(...)

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about pure Array type, there's `IndexOf()` method that will help you determine whether there's a value in it