# conditional test if integer is equivalent to a set of known integer constants C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a conditional to determine if an unknown integer 'a' is equivalent to a set of known constants, x, y or z.  In some languages, like delphi this can be done as follows:

```
if (a in [x, y, z]) then
begin
   //do something
end;
```

I am working in C#, however, so this does not work.  There are obvious ways to do it but I have been unable to find an equivalently simple way to do it and was wondering if one exists.

Thanks for ahead of time for any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value equal to ANY value in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821045/value-equal-to-any-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (new[] { x, y, x }.Contains(a))
```

(Note that this requires *either* LINQ to Objects and a `using` directive of `using System.Linq;` *or* an ugly cast to `ICollection<int>`.)

Or better, just create the set once, e.g.

```
private static readonly HashSet<int> ValidValues = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

...

if (ValidValues.Contains(a))
```

If the number of elements is fairly small, then actually an array may well be faster than a `HashSet`:

```
private static readonly int[] ValidValues = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Or wrap it in a read-only collection if you don't trust yourself not to modify it in your class.

Comment: Shit! I was a second before submitting it. Jon you rock!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using LINQ then this should work for you:

```
if (new[] { x, y, z }.Contains(a))
```

If you're not using LINQ then this would also be equiv:

```
if (-1 != Array.IndexOf(new[] { x, y, z }, a))
```

Comment: `Contains` is in `IList<T>`; there's no need for LINQ. Also, it's more idiomatic to put the constant for comparison as the RHS of `!=` in C#, IMO.

Comment: @Jon: Arrays only implement `ICollection<T>.Contains` explicitly, so avoiding LINQ in Ken's first example would necessitate a cast to `ICollection<T>`/`IList<T>`, cluttering it up quite a bit.